# Convert this Weigth/Score into List of Coulmn name with sorted according to their Weigth/Score Matrix Format using Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

Convert this Weight/Score reading from an input *.csv* file into List of Column name with sorted according to their descending Weight/Score Matrix Format using `Python Apache Beam` and write into the another *.csv* file

```
    Input .csv file
    user_id, cat_1, cat_2, cat_3, cat_4, cat_5, cat_6
    1 , 0.10, 0.2, 0.20, 0.12, 0.7, 0.6 
    2 , 0.6, 0.20, 0.12, 0.15, 0.13, 0.11    
    3 , 0.11, 0.10, 0.8, 0.12, 0.3, 0.7   


    Desired output .csv file 
    user_id, top_3_categories
    1, [('cat_3', '0.20'), ('cat_2', '0.2'), ('cat_1', '0.10')]
    2, [('cat_1', '0.6'), ('cat_2', '0.20'), ('cat_3', '0.12')]
    3, [('cat_3', '0.8'), ('cat_1', '0.11'), ('cat_2', '0.10')]
```

Comment: That is a task description, not a question. What did you try? What was the problem?

Comment: Want desired output using the given input

Comment: @Guillem Xercavins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following steps, using `pandas` produces the desired output:

```
with beam.Pipeline() as p:

    lines = p | "ReadCsv" >> ReadFromText(file_pattern="input_csv",skip_header_lines=1)

    def process_csv(line):
        import pandas as pd
        line = line.split(',')
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=[line],columns=['user_id', 'cat_1', 'cat_2', 'cat_3', 'cat_4', 'cat_5', 'cat_6']).set_index('user_id')
        df['top_3_categories'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False).iloc[:3].to_dict(OrderedDict), axis=1)
        df = df['top_3_categories'].apply(lambda x: str([(k,v) for k,v in x.iteritems()])).reset_index()

        return ",".join(list(df.iloc[0].values))

    lines = lines | "Process Data" >> beam.Map(fn=process_csv)
    lines | "Write csv" >> WriteToText(file_path_prefix="output.csv")
```

Comment: what if we have a large number of columns?
Like in my case its `4500 number of columns` in *.csv* file